# Android:How to get value of dynamically generated (Checked)Radio Button with in List Activity and where to define RadioGroup (in Layout) for List?

Tags: android

1)I used list for generating (dynamically) radio button list in list activity and list is filled from database.
I want value of checked radio button.

2)Another thing:In layout where should have i declare RadioGroup ??
before  tag or
in layout file where radio button is declared

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

from your above  description i think u need to use the custom adepter

[HERE](http://devblogs.net/2011/01/04/multicolumn-listview-with-image-icon/) is the link from the u can got the idea